# Livewire components not load in pagination click

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I'm studying livewire, and I found the following problem, some components don't load when clicking the pagination link.

Can't find anything in the documentation, and I'm new to the framework

Page where the error occurs
**fila-atendimentos.blade.php**

```
<div class="flex bg-gray-100">   
    <livewire:components.barra-lateral/> 
    <div class="relative w-full h-full flex flex-col h-screen overflow-y-hidden">
        <livewire:components.topo-mobile/> 
        <div class="w-full flex-grow p-6">
            <livewire:components.topo-desktop :titulo="$titulo"/>         
            <!--INICIO CONTAINER TABELA-->
            <div class="w-full h-full mt-5">
                <form wire:submit.prevent="">
                    <label for="default-search" class="mb-2 border-0 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sr-only ">Buscar</label>
                    <div class="relative">
                        <div class="flex absolute inset-y-0 left-0 items-center pl-3 border-0 pointer-events-none">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 " fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <input type="search" id="default-search" class="block p-4 pl-10 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-white rounded-lg border-0 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 " placeholder="Nome, CNS ou CPF">
                        <button type="submit" class="text-white absolute right-2.5 bottom-2.5 bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-900 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2"> Buscar </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!--Tabela-->
                <div class="h-screen flex flex-col justify-end w-full items-end">
                    <div class="mt-5 bg-white overflow-auto rounded-md h-screen w-full flex-col sm:pb-64 overflow-y-hidden ">
                        <table class="text-left w-full border-collapse">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="py-3 px-6 bg-grey-lightest font-bold uppercase text-sm text-grey-700 border-b border-grey-light">Data e hora de chegada</th>
                                    <th class="py-3 px-6 bg-grey-lightest font-bold uppercase text-sm text-grey-700 border-b border-grey-light">Nome</th>
                                    <th class="py-3 px-6 bg-grey-lightest font-bold uppercase text-sm text-grey-700 border-b border-grey-light">Status</th>
                                    <th class="py-3 px-6 bg-grey-lightest font-bold uppercase text-sm text-grey-700 border-b border-grey-light"></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($results as $result)
                                    <tr class="border-l-8 border-green-400 hover:bg-grey-lighter">
                                        <td class="py-3 px-6 border-b border-grey-light ">{{date("d/m/Y", strtotime($result->data_fila)) .' ÀS '.$result->hora_fila}}</td>
                                        <td class="py-3 px-6 border-b border-grey-light">{{$result->pacientes->nome}}</td>
                                        <td class="py-3 px-6 border-b border-grey-light">{{$result->status}}</td>
                                        <td class="py-3 px-6 border-b border-grey-light">
                                            <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
                                                <a class="px-3" href="{{ url('/reltorios') }}">
                                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-user-pen"></i>
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="{{ url('/reltorios') }}">
                                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-hospital-user"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>   
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <!--Paginação-->
                    <div class="mt-5 h-full justify-center content-center items-center mb-auto flex-col">
                        {{$results->links() }}
                    </div>
                    <!--Fim paginação-->
                </div>
                <!--Fim tabela-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

[page before clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjsyy.png)

[page after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xfzq.png)

How to fix this?

Comment: My guess is that your other components have more than one root node, where the first one is a html comment

Comment: You should also put `wire:key` on the root element in your loop, see here https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-cures